# gdbserver for Python

Tags: python, gdb, gdbserver

I wonder what is the flow that I need to foloow to remotely debug a Python script?

For C/CPP, on instance A I run:

```
gdbserver :1234 binary
```

And from gdb, on instance B, I run

```
gdb binary    
target remote $host:1234
```

Is there any Python alternative for this flow. Can anyone point me to a Hello world example demoing a remote debug? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a list of debugging tools:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

[rpdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb/)  is cross platform and support remote debugging.